# PHP changing form input from £ to Â£

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

I have hunted for a solution but cannot find one.  I have an html 5 page with a form that contains a £ sign (GB) and the page uses charset utf-8

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

The £ displays correctly on the web page. The contents of that form are then processed through a php page to send the form contents by e-mail.

When the e-mail arrives £ has incorrectly become Â£.

I have trawled many pages regarding character sets but cannot understand most of them, as they tell me about the problem but not the solution.

I have found a "Heath Robinson" workaround with:

```
$stall_size = str_replace(chr(194),"",$stall_size);
```

But I feel that there should be a better and more universal way of getting the correct result.

Many thanks in advance

Tog

Later Edit:

Affter reading the answer I have now added the following line to the php code:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
```

and changed the e-mail headers as suggested to:

```
// create email headers
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .=  'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . $email_from . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $email_from . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

but now the script runs without showing an error but the e-mail does not arrive at its destination :-(

Comment: Make sure the e-mail has these headers: **Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit** and **Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"** (or _text/plain_, of course). And also make sure that the script creating the e-mail is UTF-8 encoded too (UTF-8 whithout BOM).

Comment: I changed the mail headers to:// create email headers
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .=  'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . $email_from . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $email_from . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
   
 
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); but now the e-mail does not arrive at its destination :-(

Comment: whoops! How do I enter code into the comments box? OK Edited the question instead